# multiple list function did not working correctly php

Tags: php, mysql

My function:

```
function m_gen($n) {
    $q = mysql_query("select * from nume where parentid = '$n'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($q) > 0) {
        echo "<ul>\n";
        while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
            echo "<li>".$r['title'].m_gen($r['id'])."</li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
    } else {
        echo "";
    }
}
```

calling the function like this:

```
m_gen(0);
```

generates the following result:

[image]

When I call the function, the HTML is not written correctly.

The result should be:

```
<li>main3
    <ul>
        <li>sub main3 > main1</li>
        <li>sub main3 > main2</li>
        <li>sub main3 > main3</li>
        <li>sub main3 > main4</li>
        <li>sub main3 > main5</li>
        <li>sub main3 > main6</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

but, what happens is like this:

```
    <ul>
        <li>sub main3 > main1</li>
        <li>sub main3 > main2</li>
        <li>sub main3 > main3</li>
        <li>sub main3 > main4</li>
        <li>sub main3 > main5</li>
        <li>sub main3 > main6</li>
    </ul>
<li>main3</li>
```

What is wrong with the function?

I've tried to find a solution, but I did not get the results

[MySQL source](http://tny.cz/29f09c73) (pass:nume)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, it shouldn't be that, because when you do this:

```
echo "<li>".$r['title'].m_gen($r['id'])."</li>\n";
```

first it executes the m_gen function (and then again recursively if there are more levels), at the last level it echoes (because there is an echo in the recursive function), and then comes back the "parent", the function that called it, that one echoes, and so on.

you should do this:

```
echo "<li>".$r['title'];
m_gen($r['id']);
echo "</li>\n";
```